# onSingleTapUp - only for tapping on Buttons

Tags: android, onclick, gesture, touch-event

I have two `Buttons` in my `Linear Layout`. I successfully override the `onTouch` of my `Buttons` so that when I fling over them something happens. I also want to be able to click on the `Buttons` so I override `onSingleTapUp`.

The problem is that `onSingleTapUp` works not only on my `Buttons` but for everywhere else on my screen too. So is there a way to make `onSingleTapUp` only refer to tapping of `Buttons` instead of tapping anywhere on the screen?

Attempt: I noticed `MotionEvent` has a boolean `isButtonPressed(int button)` so I tried the following but it crashed my application:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.isButtonPressed(1))
        Log.d("button", "override - click event performed");
    return true;
}
```

Here is my full code:

class MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected Button bttn1, bttn2;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());

        bttn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttn1);
        bttn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttn2);

        bttn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("button1", "click event performed");
            }
        });

        bttn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                   if(mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;

            }
        });

        bttn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("button2", "click event performed");
            }
        });

        bttn2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                   if(mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {

        boolean eventConsumed=mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            if (eventConsumed)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
    }

}
```

class GestureListener:

```
package com.example.swipetest;

public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.d("button", "override - click event performed");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent ev) {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d("fling", "fling performed");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
public class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

protected static final String TAG = "MyTouchListener";
protected static final boolean D = true;

public interface MyListener{
    public void onTouch();
    public void onClick();
}

private MyListener mListener;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;


private class MyClickListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        if (D){
            Log.d(TAG, "onDown");
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (D){
            Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapUp");
        }
        mListener.onClick();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (D){
            Log.d(TAG, "onFling");
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public MyTouchListener(Context context, MyListener listener){
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyClickListener());
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (D){
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch");
    }
    mListener.onTouch();
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}

}
```

You could use it like this:

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    b.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(this, new MyListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouch() {
            if (D){
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            if (D){
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick");
            }
        }
    }));
```

Comment: is this all in the same class? -- I get an error at line b.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(this, new MyListener() {: The constructor MyTouchListener(MainActivity, new MyListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: @user2456977 You can put the code on top in a separate class.

Comment: thanks so much! this is great. I am just a little confused with the @override onTouch method in MyTouchListener: why do I need mListener.onTouch() and mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)? Can you explain what each one does and why I need both?

Comment: @user2456977 Here, the MyListener is reporting touches directly. Then the GestureDetector is sending the touches to the MyClickListener, which checks to see if the touches were clicks. The MyClickListener reports back to the MyListener to report the clicks.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it doesn't override my original button click. If I do b.setOnClickListener it will run that and also the onSingleTapUp. You know why it doesn't override the button click?

Comment: @user2456977 I think that has to do with the MyTouchListener.onTouch() returning false, you could try to return true there if you want to "consume" the event.